# Two clicks on the same selector with different behavior

Tags: jquery

I search the right way, how i can do two click on the same selector both with different behavior. My code is not working, but where is the wrong?

```
 $('.setting-panel').on({ click: function(e){  

 e.preventDefault();

 $('.inner-set').fadeIn(); }});

 $('.setting-panel').on({ click: function(e){  

 e.preventDefault();

 $('.inner-set').fadeOut(); }});
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) since you are toggling the display state of an element using fading animation.

```
$('.setting-panel').on({
    click: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.inner-set').fadeToggle();
    }
});
```